# finite-rank operators are dense in Hilbert-Schmidt operator space (even when the Hilbert spaces are NOT separable?)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $U,H$ be (not necessarily separable) $\mathbb C$-Hilbert spaces and $\operatorname{HS}(U,H)$ denote the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $U$ to $H$, i.e. $$\left\|A\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,\:H)}^2:=\sum_{i\in I}\left\|Ae_i\right\|_H^2<\infty\tag1$$ for some (and hence any) orthonormal basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ of $U$.

> Can we show that the space $\mathfrak F(U,H)$ of finite-rank operators from $U$ to $H$ is dense in $\operatorname{HS}(U,H)$?

If we define $$A_Jx:=\sum_{j\in J}\langle x,e_i\rangle_UAe_i\;\;\;\text{for }x\in U$$ for finite nonempty $J\subseteq I$, then $A_J$ clearly belongs to $\mathfrak F(U,H)$. Moreover, $$A_Ix=Ax\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in U\tag2.$$ Now, let $\varepsilon>0$. By $(1)$, $(\left\|Ae_i\right\|_H^2)_{i\in I}$ is summable and hence there is a $J\subseteq I$ with $|J|\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $K\subseteq I$ with $|K|\in\mathbb N$ and $J\subseteq K$ it holds $$\sum_{i\in I\setminus K}\left\|Ae_i\right\|_H^2<\varepsilon\tag3.$$ Thus, $$\left\|A-A_K\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,\:H)^2}=\sum_{i\in I\setminus K}\left\|Ae_i\right\|_H^2<\varepsilon\tag4$$ for all $K\subseteq I$ with $|K|\in\mathbb N$ and $J\subseteq K$. This precisely means that $(\langle\;\cdot\;,e_i\rangle_UAe_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq\mathfrak F(U,H)$ is summable in $\operatorname{HS}(U,H)$ and the sum is equal to $A$.

> But does this yield the claim? Wouldn't we need to show that there is a *sequence* $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathfrak F(U,H)$ such that $\left\|A_n-A\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,H)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$? Have we already shown this?

I'm unsure whether I'm missing something, but by the argumentation above we should be able to find for every $n\in\mathbb N$ a $J_n\subseteq I$ with $|J_n|\in\mathbb N$ and $$\left\|A-A_{J_n}\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,\:H)}<\frac1n\tag4.$$ So, we could simply take $A_n:=A_{J_n}$ ...

Comment: Up to typos, this is correct. Where do you suspect a problem? Due to (1), $Ae_i\ne0$ only for countably many $i$, which is some kind of substitution for separability.

Comment: @daw Thank you for your comment. For some reason, I was unsure whether what I've shown really yields the existence of a *sequence* $(A_n)$ with $A_n\to A$ in $\operatorname{HS}$, but from your comment I guess you agree that my argument in $(4)$ is correct, right? (And could you point out the typo(s) you've mentioned?)